# Point routes to default controller module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm currently in a situation where my Rails application has quite a few Rails Engines in it. To solve architecturally, we began using a module to namespace our models/views/controllers away from other Rails Engines that were in the app such as Devise, AlchemyCMS, and Spree.

The issue is that when you create a new route for `main_app` I find that I always have to do this:

```
get '/cart' => 'primary/orders#edit'
```

Instead of:

```
get '/cart' => 'orders#edit'
```

I tried using a namespace and I thought it would have helped:

```
namespace :my_application, path: nil do
  get '/cart' => 'orders#edit'
end
```

Which produced my desired route, but it caused all the routes to be as so:

```
main_app.my_application_cart_path
```

Instead of:

```
main_app.cart_path
```

Does anyone know how to provide a default *controller* for the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use scope instead of namespace:

```
 scope '/my_application' do
   get '/cart' => 'orders#edit'
 end
```